# Conditionally set Angular's ng-class based on state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ng-class

I would like to conditionally set the class of an element based on the application state (using AngularUI Router). I've tried this, but it is not working:

```
<li ng-class="{active: $state.current.name === 'state1'}">State 1</li>
<li ng-class="{active: $state.current.name === 'state2'}">State 2</li>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is `$state` in your scope?

Comment: this is a valid expression so your problem is something else, not that specific template.

Comment: charlietfl nailed it. This plunker helped me figure it out: http://plnkr.co/edit/dDCcan?p=preview

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason it didn't work was because, as @charlietfl pointed out, $state was not in scope.  So I added the following to my state's controller:

```
$rootScope.$state = $state;
```

and it worked great. [This plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dDCcan?p=preview) is a working example.

Comment: is there amy caveat for this approach?

Answer (score 28):

You could also use the `ui-sref-active` directive.

to add the class `active` to your element when the ui-router state matches use

```
ui-sref-active="active"
```

see: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active

Comment: but can you set the value of state?

Comment: i think this approach is limited to when you are using ui-sref right?

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this:

```
<li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('state1')}">State 1</li>
<li ng-class="{active: $state.includes('state2')}">State 2</li>
```

Comment: Hi May I know the reason for downgrade of the answer?

Comment: you cannot user `$state` in html

Comment: @Vipul: It is in the ui-router documentation to use is this way. try this link https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stateincludesstatename--params